# Mahout DataModel from hdfs or S3 Stream

Tags: amazon-s3, mahout

My problem is feeding data from Amazon S3 to Mahout when Mahout is expecting type `DataModel`.

I'm trying to run a Mahout application which essentially just does the simple recommendation

```
new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(DataModel);
```

I can make it work as long as I use regular filesystem and I can read stuff from Amazon S3 using something like this:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("s3n://mybucket"), conf);
FSDataInputStream userPreferencesFile = fs.open(new Path("path/to/my/file"));
```

But what I gives me is a stream, and what `PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(DataModel)` expects is Mahout `dataModel`, which is supposed to be backed up with a file.

1. I can make the recommender work on local fs.
2. I can read hdfs or S3.
3. I can't figure out how to turn hdfs stream into something that can be fed into dataModel.

I would think there is something very simple behind this that I can't see because I'm very inexperienced with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Mahout's DataModel is an abstract class for some more specific data models:

- in-memory *GenericDataModel*
- *FileDataModel* - reads data from file and store result in memory (in *GenericDataModel*)
- *JDBCDataModel* - for data that accessed via JDBC (i.e. form DB). For example MySQLJDBCDataModel
- another data models (mongoDB for example)

So you need to specify more concrete data model. Something like this:

```
...
DataModel dataModel = new FileDataModel(new File("path/to/my/file"));
PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel);
...
```

More details is here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/recommender-documentation.html

**edit:**

You **can not** just read from distributed hdfs as from normal filesystem. If you want to use hdfs (and hadoop) you have to use hadoop's I/O and create hadoop's job with mappers, reducers and mahout's imports. Run mahout recommender will look like this:

```
~$ hadoop fs -put data_dir
~$ hadoop jar $MAHOUT_HOME/mahout-core-0.8-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -s SIMILARITY_COSINE --input data_dir --output output_dir
```

You can override default org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob (or org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.pseudo.RecommenderJob for pseudodistribute computations) for use custom mappers and reducers.

Here example of source code for RecommenderJob: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.6/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/hadoop/item/RecommenderJob.java

Comment: Thank you. I may have expressed the problem not that precisely. I do know that dataModel needs to be specified and e.g. personCorrelationSimilarity expects FileDataModel. The underlying problem for me is that I can't figure out how to make FileDataModel out of hdfs input stream. As said I can make it work with the local filesystem where I can open a actual file. Thanks especially on the  document link - I managed to avoid that while googling around.

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my post about hdfs and hope that it will address to problem more precisely.